# Visibility issue of textbox when even its not created

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes, txtA and txtB, both are never shown on the display simultaneously, and in code behind when i am applying the condition to check the visibility of textbox, its coming to be true when the textbox is don't even created.

ASPX Code:

```
<%if(CurrentOrderItem.MasterModelName.ToLower().Contains("string1"))
                      { %>
                    <div class="CustomerName clearfix ">
                        <div class="txtInput width464">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server" MaxLength="12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%} %>
                    <%if (CurrentOrderItem.MasterModelName.ToLower().Contains("string2"))
                      { %>
                        <div class="txtInput width464">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" MaxLength="20" autocomplete="off"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%} %>
```

And when i check into the codebehind visibility of the not created textbox is shown as true.

Comment: Why `Convert.ToBoolean()` ? `Contains()` will return a `bool` type.

Comment: yeah removed that code, thanks, anyways do you know why the visible is true

Comment: If you removed that code then you should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, the server side code embedded in the aspx page will be excecuted during the Render phase. Which means all your controls are created and initialized with the values. So in all the events before Render, you get each control available in the codebehind with the data.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0e39s2ck(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0e39s2ck%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also as mentioned in the article, it is not good practice to embed server side code in the ASPX page, because it leads to difficult in maintainance and un expected result.

What you can do instead is that, in the code behind, in the page load you can check the values and make your controls visible or hidden

Answer (score 1):

> when i am applying the condition to check the visibility of textbox,
>   its coming to be true when the textbox is don't even created.

TextBox's Visible will always be true. Althought it is not visible in the browser, its information is stored **ViewState**.

### Other thought

Placing the c# code in ASPX page is fragile and hard to maintain.

Instead, you can easily achieve the same result using **Panel control** which renders as **html div tag**.

```
<asp:Panel ID="APanel" runat="server" CssClass="CustomerName clearfix">
    <div class="txtInput width464">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server" MaxLength="12" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="BPanel" runat="server" CssClass="CustomerName clearfix">
    <div class="txtInput width464">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server" MaxLength="20" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (CurrentOrderItem.MasterModelName.ToLower().Contains("string1"))
        {
            APanel.Visible = true;
            BPanel.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            APanel.Visible = false;
            BPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this approach, you can check Panel's Visible instead of TextBox.